# Create a new link to access all files and folders

Tags: shell, shell-script, files, symlink

I get stuck to create a shell script for a new link something like that

```
link linkPathName orginalPathName
```

I want to create a link between a new link and original path; however, both can access together. For example, if orignialPathName was a directory, it also creates a link to access all files and folders for a new link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct command in use was:

`ln -s orginalPathName linkPathName`

To view the contents of a directory, use something like:

`ls linkPathName/`

For a non-directory, use command like this:

`cat linkPathName`

Comment: yeap, I created a link; however, how can I get the content through the link ? thank you .

Comment: @minhcat_vo updated answer with an example

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind, that there are two types of links:

- symbolic ( soft ) link. it is just reference to a file or directory system wide ( [more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) ) 
   To create it use

  ```
  ln -s /path/to/original/file /path/to/link
  ```
- hard link. it is a new entry in file system, that referers to the same file (with dir it doesn't work) inside one filesystem only ( [more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) ) 
   To create it use

  ```
  ln /path/to/original/file /path/to/link
  ```

The difference and advantages of each type you can find in the wikipedia.